# How to add new columns to over 10 GB innodb mysql table without affecting production performance?

Tags: mysql, innodb, database-deadlocks

I'm straightly trying to add 3 new columns to a innodb mysql table which is over 10GB and is serving (read/write) online.

I just used `ALTER TABLE xxx add column yyy ...` as usual.

Because of the large data scale, the altering operation is extremely time-consuming(over 10 minutes).

The problem seems to be that it locks the whole table, so that it can not serve while altering.

I'm using mysql-5.6.14, which declares to support `ADD` operation online.

Is it a common issue?

or

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9746/mysql-fastest-way-to-alter-table-for-innodb

http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9746/mysql-fastest-way-to-alter-table-for-innodb

Comment: @Abs, I'm afraid it's not helpful. I actually encounter a lock table problem but I don't not why. Besides, I can not suffer any downtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see what went wrong.  Suggest you file a bug at bugs.mysql.com.

Meanwhile, you could use `pt-online-schema-change` to do the change with virtually no downtime.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried `pt-online-schema-change`. But I got a `You do not have the PROCESS privilege at /usr/bin/pt-online-schema-change line 4224, <STDIN> line 1.` Error. would you please help me to figure out the problem?

Comment: Are you running it as MySQL's root user?

Comment: Right. I have tried to run as root. It works. `pt-online-schema-change` seems to be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-create-index-overview.html#innodb-online-ddl-summary-grid

```
    Concurrent DML is not allowed when adding an auto-increment column.
```

Are you adding an auto inc column?

Comment: Actually, no. The new column is not incremental.